# Javascript compare value inside iterating interval

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am comparing a specific table column value against a scale range interval inside an array.

```
<script>
var table=document.getElementById("DataTables_Table_0");
var r=0; //start counting rows in table
while(row=table.rows[r++])
{
        cell1=row.cells[6];
        cell2=row.cells[5];
        cell3=row.cells[7]
        var score=cell1.innerText.substr(2)/cell2.innerText.substr(2);
        var scale = [['vPoor', 0.2], ['poor', 0.4], ['avg', 0.6], ['good', 0.8], ['vGood', 1]];
        for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            if (scale[i][1] <= score && score <= scale[i+1][1]) {
                cell3.classList +=  scale[i][0];
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

I defined a class for each interval but when I run the script, the last range in the `scale` array isn't applying at all on my current values in the table column.

What should I change in the `IF` statement so the comparison will be inclusive within a range of 2 consecutive `scale` values?

Comment: Is `vPoor` applying to 0 - 0.2? If so, you need `i ? scale[i - 1][1] : 0` and `scale[i][1]` However you can simply do `Math.floor(score * 5)` to get a value from 0 to 4, i.e. the array index.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors here:

1. Dealing with the last interval, `scale[i + 1]` has an index exceeding `scale`'s indices range. Solve this by adding a new range for values above 1 and stopping your loop at `scale.length - 1`
2. `classList` is a `DOMTokenList`, not a `string`, so method for adding to it is `add`, not `+` operator
3. It seems to me you want to match only one interval for each row score, in which case you must break your inner `for` loop after finding it, or you'll get 2 different classes added to your cell for values that overlap intervals (0.2, 0.4, etc.).

Simplified the problem below to illustrate it:

```js
const scores = [-.1, 0, .5, .25, .8, .92, 1, 1.5];
const cell3 = document.querySelector("#cell3");
for (score of scores) {
  var scale = [ ['vPoor', 0.2], ['poor', 0.4], ['avg', 0.6], ['good', 0.8], ['vGood', 1], ['vGood', 1e9] ];
  for (var i = 0; i < scale.length - 1; i++) {
    if (scale[i][1] <= score && score <= scale[i + 1][1]) {
      cell3.classList.add(scale[i][0]);
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(score, cell3.className);
  cell3.className = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="cell3"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I had to change where I evaluated and reset the result `cell3.className`: first version was illustrating the results poorly

Comment: BTW, `0` gives no class as result: you should probably also prepend an interval for values below 0 like `['vPoor', -1e9]` (or change the first one)